# exec statement in sql for comma separated values

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql

I have created a SP like below. where i will have to pass comma separated values to @ID parameter.I have given split function. It is working fine only if i give one value as ID. Kindly help how should i change the exec statement for the SP to give comma separated values like ('123',456) to SP

```
EXEC usp_2090_AppRej '54862','',''

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_2090_AppRej] 
@ID VARCHAR(100)
,@Comments VARCHAR(1000) = ''
,@ReturnMessage VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT

DECLARE @tblBPM TABLE (ids INT)
INSERT INTO @tblBPM
SELECT items
FROM dbo.Split(@ID, ',')
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Post 'Split' function here also.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL server try the following.

> Create database function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]
    (
      @sInputList VARCHAR(max) -- List of delimited items
      ,
      @sDelimiter VARCHAR(max) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
    )
RETURNS @List TABLE ( item VARCHAR(max) )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(max)
        WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) <> 0 
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @sItem = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, 1,
                                                       CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
                                                              @sInputList, 0)
                                                       - 1))) ,
                        @sInputList = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,
                                                            CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
                                                              @sInputList, 0)
                                                            + LEN(@sDelimiter),
                                                            LEN(@sInputList))))

                IF LEN(@sItem) > 0 
                    INSERT  INTO @List
                            SELECT  @sItem
            END

        IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0 
            INSERT  INTO @List
                    SELECT  @sInputList -- Put the last item in
        RETURN
    END
```

> Create SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_2090_AppRej]
    @ID VARCHAR(100),
    @Comments VARCHAR(1000) = '',
    @ReturnMessage VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @tblBPM TABLE ( ids INT )
    INSERT  INTO @tblBPM
            SELECT  item
            FROM    dbo.fnSplit(@ID, ',')

END
```

Comment: There are more performant techniques for parse/split functions.   I too had a similar function and was shocked at the performance gains.  Take a peek http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/